# How to determine if one string is in the same row as another string

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem:

I need to see if a string positioned in a Cell (C3) matches the Location of a string positioned in another Cell (D3).

- if the Row is the same for both of the strings, then message "STRINGS MATCH"
- if the Row of the two strings is different, then message "STRINGS DON'T MATCH".

A code sample that does this would be very appreciated.

Example of the output in the Excel spreadsheet:

## Example:

> String1 = MouseClick,
> String2 = TOOLS
>
> - if in cell C20 "MouseClick" and cell D20 "TOOLS" Match - then "STRINGS MATCH"
> - if in cell C21 "MouseClick" and cell D21 "FILE" Don't Match - then "STRINGS   DON'T MATCH"

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you're asking, the grammar is broken so the meaning is unclear.  Post some examples of what you have and what you expect and WHY you expect that.

Comment: Please provide example values of `C3`, `D3` and the intermediate cell to make this clear...

Comment: Hi Ditto and gt6989b, unfortunately i have no rights to provide pictures so that i could explain my question visually with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this.
Use this excel formula

```
=If(C3=D3,"Strings Match","Strings Don't Match")
```

Comment: Hi Dhiren, thanks for the response. But i need it in VBA code structure.

Comment: That's ok.
thaks for the help Dhiren.